# Closest element id JS

Tags: javascript, closest

Could someone help me how to get id of the closest elements to the button?

```js
 function Myfunc(ev) {
 document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML = $(#ME).closest("div").attr('id');
 }
```

```html
<div id="target1">1 div</div>
<button onclick="Myfunc(this)" id="ME">Click me to see id of those 2 elements</button>
<div id="target2">2 div</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `closest` does not do what you think. It looks upward in the hierarchy, not around.

Comment: You have some error:  should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementbyId` and `$("#ME")` instead of `$(#ME)`, However, the jquery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) checkes element's ancestors not siblings, for siblings you can use [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `.closest` does is it navigates to an *ancestor* element that matches a selector. Since the elements you want are not ancestors of the clicked element, `.closest` isn't the right tool.

I'd use `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling`:

```js
function Myfunc(elm) {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = elm.previousElementSibling.id + ' and ' + elm.nextElementSibling.id
 }
```

```html
<div id="target1">1 div</div>
<button onclick="Myfunc(this)" id="ME">Click me to see id of those 2 elements</button>
<div id="target2">2 div</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that you need to use `getElementById`, not `getElementbyId`. Also, if at all possible, attach the listener properly using JS instead of using an inline handler (which are pretty universally considered to be poor practice):

```js
document.querySelector('#ME').addEventListener('click', function() {
 document.getElementById("demo").textContent = this.previousElementSibling.id + ' and ' + this.nextElementSibling.id;
});
```

```html
<div id="target1">1 div</div>
<button id="ME">Click me to see id of those 2 elements</button>
<div id="target2">2 div</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```